# Add property to common items in array and array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an array like `['A','B','F']` and an array of objects

```
[
    {
        name:'A',
        prop1:'value1'
    },
    {
        name:'C',
        prop3:'value3'
    },
    {
        name:'E',
        prop7:'value7'
    },

]
```

I want to filter out objects where name exists in array and add property `exists:true` to the array of objects and return the updated array of objects.

So for the above case it should return

```
[
    {
        name:'A',
        prop1:'value1',
        exists:true
    },
    {
        name:'C',
        prop3:'value3'
    },
    {
        name:'E',
        prop7:'value7'
    },

]
```

I suppose it could be done with help of JavaScript Sets but not sure how. Also can this be done in linear complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve linear time complexity, you can turn your character array into a Set. Now just simply loop through the array of objects.

```js
const characters = ['A','B','F'];

const objects = [
    {
        name:'A',
        prop1:'value1'
    },
    {
        name:'C',
        prop3:'value3'
    },
    {
        name:'E',
        prop7:'value7'
    },
];

const charSet = new Set(characters);

const output = objects.map(obj => {
    if (charSet.has(obj.name)) obj.exists = true;
    return obj;
});
```

This takes `O(n + m)`, where n is the length of the character array, and m is the length of the object array.

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks